# How to paginate a list of object (not mapped domain object) using custom pagination with spring data

Tags: spring, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I have a repository called `BananaRepositoryImpl` that contains a function that return a list of BananaDTO ( *the legacy code can't return the mapped entity ( `Banana.java` ),it's a constraint and I can't change this behavior* :( )

```
public class BananaRepositoryImpl implements BananaRepository{
   @Autowired
   EntityManager em;

   public List<BananaDTO> findAllBananes(){
     //logic to get list of bananasDTO object types using Query query = em.createQuery(JPQL_QUERY_HERE);
   }
}
```

Knowing that the `BananaDTO` object is a DTO for `Banana.java` class which looks like this :

```
@Data
@Entity
public class Banana{
  private Long id;
  private Double price;
  private Double weight;
}
```

What I should do is to implement pagination over the `findAllBananes()` method so that I can return a Page using spring Data ( or another approach ).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the attributes of the `BananaDTO` is a subset of the `Banana` entities attributes you can use [class-based projection support of Spring Data JPA](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#projections.dtos), i.e. you just add a `Pageable` as a parameter to your method and return a `Page<BananaDTO>`:

```
interface BananaRepository extends CrudRepository<Banana, Long> {
    Page<BananaDTO> findAllBananes(Pageable page)
}
```